# Generate all possible combinations using a set of strings

Tags: php, math, combinations

I'm trying to generate all possible combinations of a set of strings, using each string maximum once.

- The length of the output string isn't defined (the maximum length is the number of the given strings,since you can only use them once)
- For example, the stringset `array('A','B')` would generate A,B,AB,BA.
- For example, the stringset `array('ABC', 'Z')` would generate 'ABC','Z', 'ZABC' and 'ABCZ'.
- A stringset can have identical entries, and the output does't need te be unique.For example, the stringset `array('A', 'A')` would generate 'A', 'A','AA','AA'; (I don't actually need duplicates, but I don't want the make things more difficult)

I know that 2 strings have 4 combinations (2=>4) and 3=>15, 4=>64, 5=>325 ...

Since I'm not a programmer, I found it at least 'challenging'. Nested loops where soon too complicated. An easier solution could be finding a pattern in the indexes of array with strings. But this gives me duplicate use of the strings...

```
  $strings = array('T','O','RS');
  $num = 0;
  $stringcount = count($strings);
  $variations = array(0,1,4,15,64,325,1956,13699,109600,986409);

  for($i=0;$i<$variations[$stringcount];$i++){
    $index = base_convert($num, 10, $stringcount);
    $array_of_indexes = str_split($index);
    $out='';
    for($j=0;$j<count($array_of_indexes);$j++){
     $out .= $strings[$array_of_indexes[$j]];
    }
    echo $out . '<br />';
    $num++;
  }
```

Result:
T
O
RS
OT
OO
ORS
RST
RSO
RSRS
OTT
OTO
OTRS
OOT
OOO
OORS

Not good, many duplicates + many valid combinations are not included

I know this solution is wrong in many ways, but I don't know where to start? Any Suggestions? Thx in Advance!

Comment: I think these are permutations, not combinations. And maybe not even that.

Comment: Sure seems to me a good candidate for a recursive permutation algorithm, although including each original string independently as a result is a slight departure from a "pure" permutation. The recursive terminating case would be when you have only two elements, and the recursive part would be the nth element followed by the recursive perms of the n+1th and remaining elements. Be careful, though, because permutation computations can go through the roof quickly! Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

In mathematical terminology, you are asking for all possible *nonempty ordered subsets* of the input set. In the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, the number of such sequences appears as [sequence A007526](http://oeis.org/A007526) - note that this sequence begins with 4, 15, 64, 325 exactly as you have discovered.

This problem admits a very short, efficient solution in Python, so I'm going to post that solution first:

```
def gen_nos(s):
    for i in sorted(s):
        yield i
        s.remove(i)
        for j in gen_nos(s):
            yield i+j
        s.add(i)
```

Example:

```
>>> list(gen_nos(set(['a', 'b', 'c'])))
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'ac', 'acb', 'b', 'ba', 'bac', 'bc', 'bca', 'c', 'ca', 'cab', 'cb', 'cba']
```

Note that `sorted` is not strictly necessary; it just ensures that the output is lexicographically sorted (otherwise, the elements are iterated in set order, which is essentially arbitrary).

To convert this to PHP, we have to essentially use a recursive function with an extra array parameter to hold the result:

```
function gen_nos(&$set, &$results) {
    for($i=0; $i<count($set); $i++) {
        $results[] = $set[$i];
        $tempset = $set;
        array_splice($tempset, $i, 1);
        $tempresults = array();
        gen_nos($tempset, $tempresults);
        foreach($tempresults as $res) {
            $results[] = $set[$i] . $res;
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
$results = array();
$set = array("a", "b", "c");
gen_nos($set, $results);
var_dump($results);
```

produces

```
array(15) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "ab"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "abc"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "ac"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "acb"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [6]=>
  string(2) "ba"
  [7]=>
  string(3) "bac"
  [8]=>
  string(2) "bc"
  [9]=>
  string(3) "bca"
  [10]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [11]=>
  string(2) "ca"
  [12]=>
  string(3) "cab"
  [13]=>
  string(2) "cb"
  [14]=>
  string(3) "cba"
}
```

Comment: I should point out that the last time I competently used PHP was about four years ago, so if my approach sucks and there's a better way to do what I did, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation which I have written for quite some time using basic mathematical definiton of combination and permutation. Maybe this could help.

```
<?php
/**
 * Generate all the combinations of $num elements in the given array
 *
 * @param array  $array   Given array
 * @param int    $num     Number of elements ot chossen
 * @param int    $start   Starter of the iteration
 * @return array          Result array
 */
function combine($array, $num, $start = 0) {

    static $level = 1;

    static $result = array();

    $cnt = count($array);

    $results = array();

    for($i = $start;$i < $cnt;$i++) {
        if($level < $num ) {
            $result[] = $array[$i];
            $start++;
            $level++;
            $results = array_merge($results, combine($array, $num, $start));
            $level--;
            array_pop($result);
        }
        else {
            $result[] = $array[$i];
            $results[] = $result;
            array_pop($result);
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

/**
 * Generate all the permutations of the elements in the given array
 */
function permute($array) {

    $results = array();

    $cnt = count($array);

    for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++) {
        $first = array_shift($array);

        if(count($array) > 2 ) {
            $tmp = permute($array);
        }
        elseif(count($array) == 2) {
            $array_ = $array;
            krsort($array_);
            $tmp = array($array, $array_);
        }
        elseif(count($array) == 1) {
            $tmp = array($array);
        }
        elseif(count($array) == 0) {
            $tmp = array(array());
        }

        foreach($tmp as $k => $t) {
            array_unshift($t, $first);
            $tmp[$k] = $t;
        }

        $results = array_merge($results, $tmp);

        array_push($array, $first);
    }

    return $results;
}

$strings = array('T', 'O', 'RS');
$strings_count = count($strings);


$combinations = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $strings_count; $i++) {
  $combination = combine($strings, $i, 0);
  $combinations = array_merge($combinations, $combination);
}

$permutations = array();
foreach($combinations as $combination) {
  $permutation = permute($combination);
  $permutations = array_merge($permutations, $permutation);
}

print_r($combinations);
print_r($permutations);
```

Comment: Just a heads up, the `combine()` function is expecting the `$array` to be numerically and sequentially indexed. Perhaps an `array_values()` could eliminate that concern. More work would be required if the keys were an important part of the combination.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my naive recursive implementation:

```
<?php
// Lists all ways to choose X from an array
function choose($x, array $arr) {
    $ret = array();
    if ($x === 0) {
        // I don't think this will come up.
        return array();
    } else if ($x === 1) {
        foreach ($arr as $val) {
            $ret[] = array($val);
        }
    } else {
        $already_chosen = choose($x - 1, $arr);
        for ($i = 0, $size_i = sizeof($arr); $i < $size_i; $i++) {
            for ($j = 0, $size_j = sizeof($already_chosen); $j < $size_j; $j++) {
                if (!in_array($arr[$i], $already_chosen[$j])) {
                    $ret[] = array_merge(
                        array($arr[$i]),
                        $already_chosen[$j]
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

function choose_all($arr) {
    for ($i = 1, $size = sizeof($arr); $i <= $size; $i++) {
        foreach (choose($i, $arr) as $val) {
            echo implode(":", $val).PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

choose_all(array(
    "A",
    "B",
));
echo "--".PHP_EOL;
choose_all(array(
    "ABC",
    "Z",
));
echo "--".PHP_EOL;
choose_all(array(
    'T',
    'O',
    'RS'
));
```

(No idea what I did, of course)

http://codepad.org/5OKhsCJg

Comment: Works, yes; not knowing what you did, a bit troubling. Nevertheless, I get the feeling that real-world algorithm implementations often fall into this category...

Answer (score -2):

What you require over the array is essentially a cartesian product.  This is an aspect of set mathematics and is common in database systems as well as formal modelling languages.  There will be a number of implementation solutions if you google this term for PHP.

(I've never done any PHP directly which is why I don't want to post you an incorrect (or hacky) solution, but hopefully this will help lead you down the correct path)!

Comment: Actually, no, he isn't asking for a Cartesian product. It is a kind of permutation where omissions are permitted.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow what you mean? It doesn't say omissions are permitted and from the comment (I don't actually need duplicates, but I don't want the make things more difficult), that suggests to me that a cartesian product would be better...

Comment: What sets are you taking the product of?

Comment: each individual array element in this case forms 'a set'

Comment: Nope. That just generates subsets. We want ordered subsets.