# How to list and count all possible combinations from string?

Tags: php, math

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PHP: How to get all possible combinations of 1D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834393/php-how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-1d-array)
>   [Generate all possible combinations using a set of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160843/generate-all-possible-combinations-using-a-set-of-strings)

```
$s = 'A,B,C';
```

Given a set of strings, how do you compute that it's possible to have
AAA
BBB
CCC
ABC
ACB
BCA
etc.?

Comment: @andrewsi I'm quite clueless on what PHP functions to use. I've tried `foreach` and pick a random entry x times but how do you remove duplicate and stop when there's no more to pick.

Comment: Don't go random, go in order.

Comment: Convert the string into an array using [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and refer to the dupes.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ would be:

```
do{
cout << s << endl;
}while(next_permutation(s,s+s.size());
```

so just go through all permutations.

Answer (score 0):

Find or write a function that contains a recursive loop over the array. That should return you an array with all possible combos.

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = explode($s,",")


function recursion($string, $depth, $maxdepth, $s)
{
   if($depth == $maxdepth)
       echo $string
   else
   {
      for($i = 0;$i < sizeof($s); $i++)
      {
         recursion($string+$s[$i], $depth+1, $maxdepth, $s)
      }
   }
}

recursion("",0, sizeof($s), $s)
```

of course you could make $maxdepth and $s global variables to exclude them from the parameter list