# PHP: Brute Force Dictionary Generator

Tags: php, algorithm, brute-force

I'm looking for a concept istead of a code.

I have this alphanumrical string: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890`
and I want my combination's lenght is , for example, `16`

In other words I ask the main concept to have all possible combination mixes like this:

```
a01g51bhk898qw233
```

max lenght = 16

An example in php is appreciated but since I would use it in cross-platform scripts I was also interested in the explanation of the "how to"

Very Thanks

Oscar

---

---

### Update Question

it  sound like "I take each array element and create the maximum combination limiting to 16 char"....

I try to make this simple example with 2 element string and max lenght 4

```
MyStr = "A0"
MaxLen = 4
```

So My result is

```
AAAA
A000
AA00
AAA0
A0A0
A0AA
A00A
AA0A
0000
0AAA
00AA
000A
0A0A
0A00
0AA0
00A0
```

Another more simple example, with 4 element string and max lenght 2

```
MyStr = "A012"
MaxLen = 2
```

So My result is

```
AA
A0
A1
A2
0A
00
01
02
1A
10
11
12
2A
20
21
22
```

---

Now it's more clear?

---

Comment: I found a script over internet... but the lenght of final combination is equal to string lenght

Comment: With your example, you'll get 36^16 strings. That's about 7.96E+24. I hope you have the time to process them. Ort the space to store them.

Comment: You can use recursion in this case. However please note that the number of possible 16 digit strings shall be 36^16.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to look around stackoverflow ^_^ , i did it for you you just have to limit the lenght

[How to create possible combinations of strings from string in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955978/how-to-create-possible-combinations-of-strings-from-string-in-php)

Comment: Nothing. I think that isn't the right function...I will modify my question

Answer (score 0):

This May help:

```
$string=substr(str_shuffle("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"),0,16);
```

**Explanation:**
The function `str_shuffle()` shuffles the `string` in an random way.
The function `substr()` returns first `16` characters of the random  `string`.

Comment: OP wants all combinations.

Comment: good way to generate random string but not what was asked ^_^

Comment: But in this case I might have repetitions of the same result?.. because it's random... right?

Comment: @OscarZarrus, That is very true.

Comment: @OscarZarrus -You got the code from internet you can use `substr("string",0,16)` to get first 16 characters of the string.

Comment: I'm try the Sakuya84's solution...let 's see what comes out of the egg easter

Comment: if you are trying brute force then possibilities ate an single character can be used more than once.