# Generate list of all combinations PHP

Tags: php

I want to generate a list of all possible two character strings containing alphanumerics only i.e. 36^2 combinations. I want to print this out with a linebreak between each possibility.

I hope someone could help me out with this.

Comment: What did you come up with yourself?

Comment: Please show whatever code or pseudocode you've tried.

Comment: Im assuming you mean permutations? Because if it was combinations AB would be the same as BA. And so the number of results would be `36C2` not 36^2

Comment: Duplicate of [Generate all possible combinations using a set of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160843/generate-all-possible-combinations-using-a-set-of-strings) and many, many more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just modify the `$characters` array to include all the characters you want.**

---

**Code:**

```
<?php
    $characters = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
    foreach($characters as $first){
        foreach($characters as $second){
        echo $first.$second.'<br/>';
        }   
    }
?>
```

**Output:**

```
aa
ab
ac
ad
ba
bb
bc
bd
ca
cb
cc
cd
da
db
dc
dd
```